# Different GUI resolutions in Android RelativeLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

I have a question about different resolutions in android. I have coded a xml GUI file in RelativeLayout. Ive created small pictures, and beside the pictures I want textviews. My problem occurs when I change the resolution, the textviews "texts" moves, and I am affraid this will look bad in different resolutions.

What I have done now, I for example create a image, toRightOf that image I create a textview and this textview is below another image with for example 19 pixels. 
But if I change the resolution, the 19 pixels can be to much or to low in distance, and the text from the texview will be shown in the wrong position on the screen.

How can i overcome this problem with different resolutions and creating a GUI with RealtiveLayout that defines distances in pixels. Often I want a distance around 20 pixels between different textviews as you see in my code below.

**This is my example code:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
      <ScrollView android:id="@+id/ScrollView01"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        >

      <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="fill_parent"
       android:stretchColumns="1"
       android:weightSum="1.0"
       android:background="#adaeb5">


       <TextView android:text="@+id/TextView03" android:id="@+id/TextView03"

       android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" 
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textSize="21dp"
                android:shadowDy="1.5"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:shadowColor="#212421"
                android:shadowRadius="1.5"
                android:shadowDx="1.5"/>

   <ImageView android:id="@+id/ImageView01"

       android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_below="@+id/TextView03" android:paddingTop="35px"


 />


       <ImageView android:id="@+id/ImageView02"

       android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_below="@+id/ImageView01" android:paddingTop="20px"

 />

       <ImageView android:id="@+id/ImageView03"

       android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_below="@+id/ImageView02" android:paddingTop="20px"

 />
   <ImageView android:id="@+id/ImageView04"

       android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_below="@+id/ImageView03" android:paddingTop="20px"

 />


       <TextView android:text="@+id/TextView01" android:id="@+id/TextView01"
        android:shadowDy="1.0"
        android:shadowColor="#bdbebd"
        android:shadowRadius="1.0"
        android:shadowDx="1.0"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textColor="#212421"
       android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ImageView01" android:layout_below="@+id/TextView03" android:paddingTop="36px"/>

       <TextView android:text="@+id/TextView02" android:id="@+id/TextView02"
        android:shadowDy="1.0"
        android:shadowColor="#bdbebd"
        android:shadowRadius="1.0"
        android:shadowDx="1.0"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textColor="#212421"
       android:layout_below="@+id/TextView01" android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ImageView02" android:paddingTop="25px"/>

       <TextView android:text="@+id/TextView04" android:id="@+id/TextView04"
        android:shadowDy="1.0"
        android:shadowColor="#bdbebd"
        android:shadowRadius="1.0"
        android:shadowDx="1.0"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textColor="#212421"
       android:layout_below="@+id/TextView02" android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ImageView03" android:paddingTop="15px"/>

       <TextView android:text="@+id/TextView05" android:id="@+id/TextView05"
        android:shadowDy="1.0"
        android:shadowColor="#bdbebd"
        android:shadowRadius="1.0"
        android:shadowDx="1.0" 
       android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textColor="#212421"
       android:layout_below="@+id/TextView04" android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ImageView04" android:paddingTop="19px"/>



       <TextView android:text="@+id/TextView07" android:id="@+id/TextView07"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textSize="21dp"
                android:shadowDy="1.5"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:shadowColor="#212421"
                android:shadowRadius="1.5"
                android:shadowDx="1.5"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" android:layout_below="@+id/TextView05" android:paddingTop="30px"/>

       <TextView android:text="@+id/TextView08" android:id="@+id/TextView08"
        android:shadowDy="1.0"
        android:shadowColor="#bdbebd"
        android:shadowRadius="1.0"
        android:shadowDx="1.0"
        android:paddingLeft="20px"
        android:paddingRight="25px" 
       android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textColor="#212421" android:textSize="16dp"
       android:layout_below="@+id/TextView07" android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ImageView05" android:paddingTop="20px" android:paddingBottom="20px"/>



       <Button android:id="@+id/help_button2" android:layout_below="@+id/TextView08"

       android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"

       android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" android:text="Previous" />




      </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

/thx in advance

Answer (score 0):

Changes `dp` wherever you have written `px`. This is supported and suggested by android itself....